# Windows Services can't create subprocesses?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, service, popen

I'm writing a Python script which have to run some commands on a Windows system. The way that I choose is to use `subprocess.Popen` because I need to capture and pipe some outputs. I have compiled it, and everything works fine when I run the `.exe` manually.

The script has been thought to run in every system start, so I have created a Windows Service which executes it, and here is when the issue comes. Basically, it runs and can do some other things, so the service was created succesfully, but can't create a subprocess and execute the commands on it.

Because it works fine when I run it manually, I assume that there aren't mistakes in the code, and the issue is related to something about Windows Services. Maybe it can't create child subprocesses? Did someone get it?

Comment: Initially a workstation has two sessions. Session 0 is for services, and Session 1 is for the first interactive logon. A Session contains WindowStation objects, which contain Desktop objects, which contain User objects such as windows. Each Session has a WindowStation named "WinSta0", which is the only one that's allowed to interact with the Session user. Initially it has a secure "Winlogon" Desktop for logon and UAC consent, and a "Default" Desktop for the shell.

Comment: Session 0 WinSta0, however, is non-interactive, plus each service process uses a WindowStation created for its LSA logon session. Thus a service cannot simply create an interactive process the regular way via `subprocess.Popen` (i.e. `CreateProcess`). The Session that's currently attached to the physical console can be queried via `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`, or find an active Session (including remote sessions) via `WTSEnumerateSessions`. If you want to start a Process in another Session, obtain a Token for it via `WTSQueryUserToken` and create the process via `CreateProcessAsUser`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem (on Windows Server 2012 R2), and didn't really want to dive into the level of Win32 API calls to get my (GUI application running without caring about what is on the GUI) exe on the right session desktop. However, I did notice that we had another process that was running correctly, as part of a MSBuild script.

The workaround that I came up with was to generate a very simple msbuild file to execute the process I wanted to launch and run that instead. Seems to work well, but might not be happy if you need system pipes in/out of your .exe.

Wasn't working:

```
subprocess.call("MyExe.exe")
```

Does work:

```
with open("temp.msbuild", "w") as mb:
    mb.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>\n')
    mb.write('<Project DefaultTargets="Run" xmlns="' 
             + 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'
             + '">\n')
    mb.write('  <Target Name="Run">\n')
    mb.write('    <Exec Command="MyExe.exe"\>\n')
    mb.write('  </Target>\n')
    mb.write('</Project>\n')
subprocess.call("msbuild temp.msbuild")
os.remove("temp.msbuild")
```